# Why do I got a SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception error when I'm using a modulo on an int obtained by a modulo of a different integer in my code?

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve a problem in hackerrank but I got a SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception error when I tried to compile my code. 
After a few trial and errors, I figured out that the problem lies between the part which I wrote    "if(y%m==0)" because the m variable apparently contain an integer which was obtained by a modulo operation of another integer. Can somebody please explain to me why this happened and how to fix it? Here are my codes that I wrote :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y,z,m,total;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    for(int i = 0; i<x; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &y);
        for(z=y; z>0;z/=10)
        {
            if(z==y)
            total = 0;
            m=(z%10);
            if(y%m==0)
            {
                total++;
            }
        }
        printf("\n%d\n", total);
    }
}
```

Comment: If z is a multiple of 10 then m will be set to 0.  When you evaluate y%m you are dividing by 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the user enters a `y` value that's divisible by 10, then `z` will also be divisible by `10`. Then, when you set `m=(z%10);`, `m` is set to 0. Doing `y % m` in such a situation is a division by 0 error.

Maybe consider first checking to make sure `m` isn't 0?

```c
if(m == 0 || y%m==0)
{
  total++;
}
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/SimultaneousInfantileBackground)